# Cant get data to list the five latest messages by using JSON and Webapi

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

I want to list the five latest messages in a listbox by using JSON and WebApi. 
Somehow it doesn't show any data on the listbox

JQuery method:

```
<script>

    function get_latest_messages(Namn) {
        // Handle your incomming data from the api
        function handleJson (messages) {
            // the data parameter is supposed to be your json
            for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++)  {
                $("#MessList").append(data[i].UIdFrom);
                $("#MessList").append(data[i].Text);
            }
        }

        // Call
        $.getJSON('http://localhost:51486/api/message/get?username=' + Namn, handleJson);
    }
</script>
```

The listbox the messages is shown in:

```
<div runat="server" id="SenastDiv">
    <asp:Label ID="Text" runat="server" Text="Dina fem senaste meddelanden"></asp:Label>
    <asp:ListBox ID="MessList" runat="server" Width="250 px"></asp:ListBox>
</div>
```

The api Controller:

namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers

```
public class MessageController : Controller
{
    DALLager d = new DALLager();

    public IEnumerable<GetFiveLatest> Get(string username)
    {
        IEnumerable<GetFiveLatest> messages = d.getFiveLatest(username);
        return messages;
    }
}
```

The method in the datalayer:

```
public List<GetFiveLatest> getFiveLatest(string userName)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["InstabandDBEntities"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        Meddelande mess = new Meddelande();
        List<GetFiveLatest> lista = new List<GetFiveLatest>();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 5 UIdFrom, Text FROM Message WHERE UIdTo='" + userName + "'ORDER BY Text DESC", conn);
        SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            GetFiveLatest message = new GetFiveLatest();
            message.Text = (dataReader["Text"].ToString());
            message.UIdFrom = (dataReader["UIdFrom"].ToString());
            lista.Add(message);
        }
        conn.Close();
        return lista;
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(exe = "Följande fel inträffade: " + ex.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a MVC `Controller`.  You should be using an `ApiController`.

Comment: @Shoxxer It's kinda hard to help without more details.  Did the request to your message actually get sent?  Did the controller receive the message?  What media type was the response body?